# How to write JSON structure when retrieving the datas from mySQL DB?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I'm trying to get the datas from Database(MySQL) to JSON, But i face the structure which is missing

Tried this kind of Queries below,

This is the code which i have used

P.S : i have used MySQLi only not MySQL

```
// MySQL query, maybe you already have something similar
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 5';
$res = mysql_query($query);

// Push all records from the database into a single array
$users = array();
$users['users'] = array(); // Your "users" key for JSON
while ($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $users['users'][] = $user;
}

// Encode and output that array as JSON, then end the script
echo json_encode($users);
exit();
```

jSON Output Expected :

```
{   
    name : Electronics // base / parent category name
    category_id : 1
    "category": [
        {
            "category_id": "4",
            "category_name": "Mobiles",
            "image_url": "mobile.jpg",
            "parent_category": "1",
        },
        {
            "category_id": "5",
            "category_name": "Desktop",
            "image_url": "desktop.jpg",
            "parent_category": "1",
        },
        {
            "category_id": "6",
            "category_name": "Laptop",
            "image_url": "laptop.jpg",
            "parent_category": "1",
        }
    ],

    name : TV & Appliances // base / parent category name
    category_id : 2
    "category": [
        {
            "category_id": "7",
            "category_name": "TV",
            "image_url": "television.jpg",
        },
        {
            "category_id": "8",
            "category_name": "Washing Machine",
            "image_url": "washing-machine.jpg",
        },
        {
            "category_id": "9",
            "category_name": "Refridgerator",
            "image_url": "refridgerator.jpg",
        }
    ],

    name : Sports & Fitness // base / parent category name
    category_id : 3
    "category": [
        {
            "category_id": "10",
            "category_name": "Cricket",
            "image_url": "cricket.jpg",
        },
        {
            "category_id": "11",
            "category_name": "Badminton",
            "image_url": "badminton.jpg",
        },
        {
            "category_id": "12",
            "category_name": "Football",
            "image_url": "football.jpg",
        }
    ],

    "success": 1
}
```

But i'm not getting the expected result, Here how do i get the nested category - sub-category in array as custom defined format.

Comment: `jSON Output Expected` - is not possible as you have duplicate keys at the same level, such as `name`  in other words those need to be in their own array.  I dont see how that code even comes remotely close to this JSON `// Your "users" key for JSON` - there is no Users key in that example JSON .... etc.

Comment: We don’t even have any idea what the data you are reading from the `users` table looks like, where you expect to get those categories from ... (Or why a table that you apparently want to get some kind of product data from would be named `users` in the first place.) Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.